# three.js WebGLRenderer()

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I am passing in a canvas DOMelement to my call to the WebGLRenderer() like this:

```
var jqc = $('#myCanvas'); //get canvas with jQuery;
var par = {canvas:jqc.get()}; //create parameter object with canvas DOMElement in it
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(par); //create new WebGLRenderer using myCanvas
//program fails in constructor
```

Is there something that I am missing?

I have tried the above whilst not giving the constructor any parameters and the code works fine it's just when using the par object to try and get it to use the canvas I already have on the page, that it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns an array, even if it only contains one element. Try:

```
var par = { canvas: jqc.get(0) };
```

Comment: gah so simple. I knew it returned an array I just assumed if it was only an array of one it would return the DOMElement on its own, I tried alert(par.canvas); and it alerted [Object HTMLCanvasElement] so I though it was fine. It does this whether I use get() or get(0). Ah well thanks for the answer, spot on.